# How to add libgcc to .so file

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I have a third-party shared object file (library file) a.so, but when I does
`ldd -d -r a` it gives lots of undefined symbols like `undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE`. I checked and googled and found out that this symbol is coming from standard `libstdc++`. So to make this `a.so` work, i did following :
`g++ -fPIC -static-libgcc -L. -shared -o liba.so -Wl,-soname,liba.so -L. a.so`
Now when i does `ldd -d -r liba`, i gets all references.
But here problem is I want to share liba.so with my application which will run on different linux machine where `a.so` will not found by `liba.so`.
Is there a way where I can remove undefined symbols by adding std libs and provided third party shared library into single shared object and which i can use?

Comment: Use 'nm' utility to find out where this symbol comes from: `libgcc_s.so` isn't the asnswer, as it doesn't contain C++-related symbols. (My guess is libstdc++.so)

Comment: Thanks!! Yes your guess is right, it is libstdc++.so

Comment: Have you actually tested this `a.so` and experienced problems? What error messages did you get? (Was the main program written in C++? C++ plugins can only be used from C++ main-programs)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way where I can remove undefined symbols by adding std libs and provided third party shared library into single shared object and which i can use?

No. On must UNIX systems (with an exception of AIX) the `.so` is a *final* product of the linker, and further link manipulation is impossible.

Now, your actual problem appears to be that `libthird_party.so` does not have a dependency on `libgcc_s.so.1` in its `.dynamic` section. It *may* be possible to binary-patch this library using `ELF` editing tools, such as `elfsh` [link](http://elfsh.asgardlabs.org/).

Finally, you actually likely *do not have* a problem to solve in the first place. Since you are shipping this library with your own executable, so long as that executable itself links against `libgcc_s.so.1`, the symbols that 3rd party library requires will be present anyway.

Comment: Java code `System.loadLibrary(libthird_party.so)` is first going to call and then my own executable. I need to load both libraries. On first loading itself I am getting error.

Comment: @user2018303 Your comment doesn't make any sense. What does your executable have to do with Java?